# How to not change the scroll position when the datasource change Xtragrid

Tags: winforms, .net-4.0, devexpress, xtragrid, devexpress-windows-ui

I have a windows form application with DevExpress Xtragrid Suit.
I have a screen that has a grid with many columns and rows, because of this  i dont want to change the scroll position when i change or reload the data to the DataSource property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you're only allowing one row to be selected at a time. That is,`GridView.OptionsSelection.MultiSelect == false`.

That being the case, you can handle the `FocusedRowChanged` event, and store information from that row (i.e, the value from a column or combination of columns that it unique within your data set) that will allow you to get back to it again. Then, when you need to update the data source, use the `GridView.LocateByValue` method to get the row handle of the row that had focus, and set the `GridView.FocusedRowHandle` to that row handle.

Note that you cannot simply save off the row handle before updating your data source, as row handles may change if you add or remove rows from the data source.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should stock your `SelectedRowHandle` and `FocusedColumn` somewhere. This [link](http://www.devexpress.com/support/center/Question/Details/Q280410) might help you.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i'm using Windows Forms and the link you passed is for WPF Projects